# Replication es.search (index_results.execute()) for es.scroll

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch-py

I am using the python dsl library

When I do a standard search I use execute(), this is a method that will return a Response object (https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html).  Looks to have .search at the heart of it

In some cases I to use scroll .  This works, but it returns a dictionary.

What I want to do is use scroll but to return a response in the same way that execute() does

The DSL Elasticsearch function does this

```
def execute(self, ignore_cache=False):
    """
    Execute the search and return an instance of ``Response`` wrapping all
    the data.

    :arg response_class: optional subclass of ``Response`` to use instead.
    """
    if ignore_cache or not hasattr(self, '_response'):
        es = connections.get_connection(self._using)

        self._response = self._response_class(
            self,
            es.search(
                index=self._index,
                doc_type=self._doc_type,
                body=self.to_dict(),
                **self._params
            )
        )
    return self._response
```

What I need to do (I think) is replicate that but for scroll, so that all the data returned is of the same type.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the `scan` method on the `Search` object which return an iterator of the documents using the scan/scroll API under the hood - https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#pagination

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am aware of scan, but in my case the Elasticsearch calls will be over http, so I can use the scan method.  Looking further into this, I think the execute function returns a AttrList rather than a Dict.  What I really want to do I think, is append a function to the Elasticsearch class (class Search(Request)) as if it was written in the file.  That is more a general Python question which may not even be possible.

Comment: `scan` works perfectly fine over http, I am confused as to what you are missing there. What is your desired output? Just all the documents matching the query as a list? Then just do `list(s.scan())`.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  Basically I want an external application to call something like example.com/my-content  the first time they call it they get say 1-100, then the second time 101-200 etc until the response is empty.

Comment: I see, then you want to use the `search_after` functionality. You can see how it would work in https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/pull/806/files#diff-6d2007cf2f50e2f48e1f67e5803ff090R388